# Make CSS of paragraph elements different if they are empty?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The client is using a WYSIWYG editor to generate HTML like the following. Normally, there should be no margin or padding for the paragraph elements. However, if the client wants there to be a line break, he will press enter twice in the editor, which will generate an empty paragraph element. This empty paragraph element should have a margin-top of 15px.

So basically, here's an example of the HTML generated. The margin for the paragraph elements with content in them should be 0, but the margin for the paragraph tags that are empty should be margin-top:15px

```
<p>Paragraph 1 content goes here</p>
<p>Paragraph 2 content goes here</p>
<p></p>
<p>Paragraph 3 content goes here</p>
<p>Paragraph 4 content goes here</p>
<p>Paragraph 5 content goes here</p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p>Paragraph 6 content goes here</p>
```

I know this is an odd request, and the only reason we are dealing with this issue is because of the much hated WYSIWYG editor, but I'm wondering if there's any way in CSS to accomplish this, or if I need to resort to Javascript/JQuery? If so, how would I do it most efficiently in Javascript/JQuery?

Comment: Use the [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) pseudo-class

Comment: @crush As long as you keep an eye on that browser support section and are ok with it - not available in IE8.

Comment: Could you please show us the steps and things you already tried prior to posting here? This would show us what your tried and at the same time would prevent losing our time trying things you already did.

Comment: @JoeEnos I didn't see where he specified needing to support IE8.

Comment: @crush Just a general thought to always keep in mind. IE8 still has a share of the market, so IMO you should always at least consider your IE8 users when doing something like this. Even if you end up doing it anyway, you should at least know what will happen to your IE8 users.

Comment: p:empty worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
p:empty { margin: 15px 0 0; }
```

Be warned that a simple space will keep the `:empty` pseudo-selector from being applied.

Comment: He actually specified the margin he wanted to be `margin-top: 15px` as well :)

Comment: This worked perfectly. I need to brush up on my knowledge of CSS pseudo-classes. Thanks!